# Restrict runnable Docker Image in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

How can I whitelist containers which are allowed to run inside PCF? We want to have control over the containers which are running in pcf.

Answer (score 1):

As I write this Cloud Foundry doesn't directly offer this functionality, but I suppose you could restrict network access so that you can't get to the public registries and can only get to a private registry that you control which only has approved images.

You can use something like [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/), [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) to run your own registry.

If your custom registry does not have a trusted TLS certificate, you may need to add it to the list of [trusted certs in Ops Manager](https://docs.pivotal.io/platform/application-service/2-7/operating/docker-registry.html#ops-man) or [configure PAS and add it to the Private Docker insecure registry allow list](https://docs.pivotal.io/platform/application-service/2-7/operating/configure-pas.html#application-containers-config).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I already thought about this. Hoped for a similar functionality like in OpenShift. Thank you.